# Send form data with application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding, inside payload

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, paypal, url-encoding, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 esb 4.8.0 and trying to make a REST call to PayPal API OAuth request ([request with title OAuth Request/Response](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#authentication--headers)). The content type of request needs to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I tried to do this in several ways.

([for better code view please refer this](http://pastebin.com/gSri3XSi))

1. `<payloadFactory media-type="json">
       <format>
          {
             "grant_type":"client_credentials"
          }
       </format>

   </payloadFactory>

   <property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2"/>

   <call>
     <endpoint>
       <http method="post" uri-template="https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials"/>
       <property name="grant_type" value="client_credentials"/>
     </endpoint>
   </call>`

Yes, I have included 3 possible (seems possible) ways at once in the code (and tried as well) to make this call. But the post parameters are not passing to the end point correctly. I'm getting the following response with HTTP/1.1 400 code.

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"grant_type is a required parameter"}
```

Appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same scenario with the paypal to get the oAuth token. Refer the following configurations

```
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
<property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <POST xmlns="">
            <grant_type>client_credentials</grant_type>
        </POST>
    </format>
    <args/>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
<send>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"/>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```